# Django send multiple emails with difference subject, body at once

Tags: django, email, smtp

I want to send a survey to my customers so I want each email subject, body contain customer's name.
Is it possible to send all emails at once or I have to send email multiple times, each time for a specific customer throughout SMTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use send_mass_mail()

```
message1 = ('Subject here', 'Here is the message', 'from@example.com',
         ['first@example.com', 'other@example.com'])

message2 = ('Another Subject', 'Here is another message',
         'from@example.com', ['second@test.com'])

send_mass_mail((message1, message2), fail_silently=False)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#send-mass-mail

Answer (score 0):

SMTP accepts a single message, to possibly multiple recipients. Assuming you previously used bcc, that could be a single message.

If you're customizing the subject, or body of the email; there will have to be multiple mail() calls and multiple SMTP calls